# Using where() on variable result from Laravel 5 Query Builder

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I have a database structure like this (to simplify):

```
pets table
- id
- name
- owner_id

owners table
- id
- name
- city_id

cities table
- id
- name
```

I'd like to print the full list of cities with, next to each one of them, the number of pets who live there. This is how I was trying to approach this problem:
This is my controller function:

```
// get all pets and associate them with the matching owner record, so every pet has also a city where it lives in.
$pets = DB::table('pets')->join('owners', 'pets.owner_id', '=', 'owners.id')->get();

// get all cities
$cities = DB::table('cities')->get();

// pass values to the view
return View('cities_stats',array('pets'=>$pets, 'cities'=>$cities));
```

On my Blade template:

```
@foreach($cities as $city)
    <li>
        {{ $city->name }}: // city name
        {{ $pets->where('city_id', $city->id)->count() }} pets // number of pets in this city
    </li>
@endforeach
```

The problem is that it of course throws an error. I cannot use neither `where()` nor `count()` in `{{ $pets->where('city_id', $city->id)->count() }}` because `$pets` is an array.
What can I do then?

P.S. I'm using Laravel 5.0.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to do the inverse for simplicity.

```
$cities = DB::table('cities')
->leftjoin('owners'...)
->leftjoin('pets'...)
->select(...)
->get();
```

Or use eager loading

```
$cities = City::with('owner.pets')->get();
```

In your view, you simply loop and voila!

Answer (score 0):

You should pass to view a not query result but builder itself. So just remove `->get()`

```
$pets = DB::table('pets')->join('owners', 'pets.owner_id', '=', 'owners.id');
```

Now it is not an array.